# How to find the intersection line from plotting data of 2 groups and How to solve it (e.g. remove or delete it)

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, intersection

I have 2 group of data points,

herewith is group A

```
dataA= {{86.0365, 38.6844}, {86.0526, 38.6998}, {86.069, 38.7154}, {86.085, 38.7308}, {86.1087, 38.7534}, {86.1332, 38.7766}, {86.1491, 38.7918}, {86.1651, 38.8068}, {86.1976, 38.8378}, {86.2377, 38.8758}, {86.2779, 38.9136}, {86.2942, 38.9289}, {86.3347, 38.9672}, {86.359, 38.99}, {86.3834, 39.0129}, {86.3996, 39.0281}, {86.4157, 39.0432}, {86.432, 39.0585}, {86.4562, 39.0812}, {86.4723, 39.0963}, {86.4968, 39.1191}, {86.5211, 39.1418}, {86.5534, 39.1719}, {86.5781, 39.1947}, {86.6104, 39.2249}, {86.6347, 39.2472}, {86.668, 39.278}, {86.6841, 39.2931},
 {86.7082, 39.3152}, {86.7248, 39.3306}, {86.741, 39.3455}, {86.7573, 39.3605}, {86.7736, 39.3756}, {86.7898, 39.3904}, {86.8066, 39.4058}, {86.8229, 39.4209}, {86.839, 39.4357}, {86.8554, 39.4506}, {86.872, 39.4658}, {86.8965, 39.4882}, {86.9126, 39.503}, {86.9294, 39.5183}, {86.9456, 39.5332}, {86.962, 39.5481}, {86.9784, 39.5631}, {86.9945, 39.5776}, {87.012, 39.5936}, {87.0259, 39.6062}, {87.0506, 39.6289}, {87.0446, 39.6248}, {86.9309, 39.6007}, {86.9319, 39.6008}, {87.1508, 39.7224}, {87.3654, 39.9241}, {87.5335, 40.0905}, {87.7128, 40.2768},
 {87.884, 40.4632}, {88.0522, 40.6547}, {88.2157, 40.8498}, {88.3747, 41.0487}, {88.5293, 41.2511}, {88.6793, 41.4572}, {88.8248, 41.6666}, {88.9656, 41.8794}, {89.1018, 42.0955}, {89.2334, 42.3148}, {89.3602, 42.5372}, {89.4823, 42.7625}, {89.5998, 42.9908}, {89.7124, 43.2221}, {89.8204, 43.4563}, {89.9238, 43.6932}
}
```

And herewith is group B

```
dataB= {{94.6467, 45.3748}, {94.2518, 45.1257}, {93.8591, 44.8731}, {93.4686, 44.6171}, {93.0804, 44.3577}, {92.6944, 44.0949}, {92.3108, 43.8287}, {91.9295, 43.5593}, {91.5506, 43.2865}, {91.174, 43.0104}, {90.7999, 42.731}, {90.4282, 42.4484}, {90.059, 42.1625}, {89.6924, 41.8734}, {89.3282, 41.5812}, {88.9666, 41.2858}, {88.6076, 40.9872}, {88.2513, 40.6855}, {87.8976, 40.3807}, {87.5465, 40.0729}, {87.1982, 39.762}, {86.8525, 39.448}, {86.5097, 39.1311}, {86.1696, 38.8112}
}
```

I plotted both of groups point data in Mathematica.
[image]

How to find the intersection line from plotting data above using mathematica programming and How to solve it (e.g. remove or delete it).

Answer (score 1):

My answer is that:

**What you are asking does not make much sense for that given set of data.**

Your data does not describe a function, as around `x->87` there is more than one [Ordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinate)

```
ListPlot[
 dataA
, PlotRange -> {{86.8, 87.2}, {39, 40}}
, Joined -> True
,  Mesh -> All
]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Even if you were to fix that deleting the offending data points, for example

```
Delete[dataA, {{50}, {51}, {52}}]
```

The two data sets seems approach asymptotically

```
ListPlot[
 {
  Delete[dataA, {{50}, {51}, {52}}]
  , dataB
  }
 , PlotRange -> {{All, 88}, {38, 41}}
 , Joined -> True
 , Mesh -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plotting the difference of a linear [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) suggest three solutions, that is, if you don't considered this features just noise.

```
Plot[
 Interpolation[Delete[dataA, {{50}, {51}, {52}}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1][x]
  - Interpolation[dataB, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x]
 , {x, 86.17, 87}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solutions can be fond using [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
FindRoot[
 Interpolation[Delete[dataA, {{50}, {51}, {52}}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1][x]
  - Interpolation[dataB, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x]
 , {x, 87}
 ]
```

> ```
> {x -> 86.86}
> ```

But beware that these are heavily dependent of the [`InterpolationOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html), so the values are just an artefact, and I think you can not define a intersection for that set of data.

```
FindRoot[
 Interpolation[Delete[dataA, {{50}, {51}, {52}}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2][x]
  - Interpolation[dataB, InterpolationOrder -> 2][x]
 , {x, 87}
 ]
```

> ```
> {x -> 87.0026}
> ```

```
Plot[
 Interpolation[Delete[dataA, {{50}, {51}, {52}}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2][x]
  - Interpolation[dataB, InterpolationOrder -> 2][x]
 , {x, 86.17, 87}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]